# Save preferences

Tags: android

I'm a beginner at Android programming, unfortunately I have a problem :)

I have method **writeSettings()** in my game in which I'm trying to save some variables to use it when want to load last game by **readSettings()** method. There are parameters such as **first(second)PlayerName, first(second)PlayerScore** and so on. I'm trying to use SharedPreferences to save them, but I get "Force Close" dialog, when starting program.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); //Global variable

    private void writeSettings() {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("timeSave", time);
                editor.putString("firstPlayerNameSave", firstPlayerNameTextView.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("secondPlayerNameSave", secondPlayerNameTextView.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("firstPlayerScoreSave", firstPlayerScoreTextView.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("secondPlayerScoreSave", secondPlayerScoreTextView.getText().toString());
                editor.putInt("nowPlayerSave", nowPlayer);        
                editor.commit();

        }


       private void readSettings() {
    //"time" parameter program reads in another method
                    firstPlayerNameTextView.setText(preferences.getString("firstPlayerNameSave", ""));
                    secondPlayerNameTextView.setText(preferences.getString("secondPlayerNameSave", ""));
                    firstPlayerScoreTextView.setText(preferences.getString("firstPlayerScoreSave", ""));
                    secondPlayerScoreTextView.setText(preferences.getString("secondPlayerScoreSave", ""));
                    nowPlayer = preferences.getInt("nowPlayerSave", -1);

            }
```

How I could know, problem appears in first entry of writeSettings().
But I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Sorry for my English.

**upd.**

```
12-23 16:23:31.334: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.game/com.game.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.Activity.getLocalClassName(Activity.java:3410)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.Activity.getPreferences(Activity.java:3444)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at com.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:69)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
12-23 16:23:31.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(410):     ... 11 more
```

Game.java:69 is a `SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: What about the exception? You should see something in your log cat

Comment: Yep, which problem appears? You should copy the error that is in your debug output (log).

Comment: Could you post the code near line 69? tnx

Comment: Upper 69 just declarations of variables, lower onCreate() begins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context).edit();
                editor.putString("firstPlayerNameSave", firstPlayerNameTextView.getText().toString());              
                editor.commit();
```

And to read:

```
firstPlayerNameTextView.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context).getString("firstPlayerNameSave", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is almost identical to what martipelant suggested.

Getting the editor:

```
Editor preferenceEditor = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.android.myapp",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

And reading:

```
       mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.android.myapp",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `Activity.getPreferences()` is a wrapper for `Context.getSharedPreferences(String, int)` where String is the name of the activity.
It should be used only for accessing preferences that are private to this activity.
Try to change the code

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: Oh,I'm stupid :) Initialization of **preferences** was outside of onCreate. Thanks, your question helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Save preferences in android shared preferences

`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).edit(); editor.putString("firstPlayerNameSave", firstPlayerNameTextView.getText().toString()); editor.apply();`